# Loading .txt file within JAR

Tags: java, properties, fileinputstream

I've got a `db.properties.txt` file with my package `com.noteu`

Within the same package as the file I'm trying to load it in the constructor of a properties object within a Database class like as follows :

```
properties.load(Database.class.getResourceAsStream("db.properties.txt"));
```

However I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException` as follows :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Properties.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.noteu.Database.get(Database.java:24)
    at com.noteu.menus.Signin.checkSignedInStatus(Signin.java:52)
    at com.noteu.menus.Signin.<init>(Signin.java:253)
    at com.noteu.Main.main(Main.java:33)
```

Comment: Consider using the path "/com/noteu/db.properties.txt" instead (or "com/noteu/db.properties.txt" I usually try both when I have trouble). If the properties file exists in the same directory as the Database class and you're not using a static context, you could try using getClass().getResourceAsStream() instead (using the relative path)

Comment: Have you verified that the .jar file contains a com/noteu/db.properties.txt entry?  If it doesn't, there may be an issue with how the .jar was packaged.

Comment: Open the jar (zip format) with 7zip/WinZip or whatever, and check that the file is there: _case-sensitive_, in the package folder. It might be that you need to place the file not under /src/(main/)java but /src/main/resources/com/noteu/ or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change type of file to `.properties`, `properties.load();` loads `properties` file not `txt` file as stream.

```
public void load(InputStream inStream) throws IOException
```

Reads a property list (key and element pairs) from the input byte stream.

Modified code :

```
properties.load(Database.class.getResourceAsStream("db.properties"));
```

To load `.txt` file instead of properties file you have to create `FileInputStream` instance.

```
FileInputStream fis new FileInputStream("myfile.txt");
props.load(fis)
```

> If my solutions are not working please make sure that your path is
>   correct.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am agree extension is irrelevant, but java itself specifies that `load()` method takes input stream. I have specified another option using `FileInputStream` is it working.

Comment: The OP is (obviously) attempting to load an embedded resources, the likely cause is a bad path

Comment: You do not have to read a `.txt` file using a FileInputStream.  Absolutely any type of file may be read using Class.getResourceAsStream.